# Story/webnovel where the main character is neglected by her family and time travels to save her sister and mother

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, medieval

I read a story a year or two ago (pretty sure it was a web or light novel) that I haven't been able to find since.  It starts off similarly to 'My Fiancée Is In Love With My Little Sister.'

The main character is a duke's daughter, the older of the two and constantly loses out to her sweet, innocent, sickly younger sister.  Her crown-prince fiancée is in love with her and ditches her for her sister.  But as you read, you learn that her younger sister is only her half-sister--they share their ducal father, but the younger's mother was a foreign princess.  Her own mother, and the duke's wife, was the princess' servant.  Her mother has been poisoning her younger sister to keep her sick (not enough to kill).  Her mother attempts suicide as a result as well.  Time travel to stop it and other shenanigans ensue.

I may not be remembering this next bit right, but I think she's accused of arranging an accident or something for her sister, when they're actually dealing with foreign assassins.

As far as I've read into this story, there's also no romance element--which is unusual for the genre.

Comment: Do you know the original language, e.g. was this a Japanese/Korean/Chinese webnovel translated into English? If so, do you have any idea if there's a webtoon/manga adaptation of it?

Comment: My bet would be Japanese or Korean; Chinese novels often have a flavor this one lacked.  And I'm not sure if it has a webtoon or Manga adaptation.